# Not work Google Map Android API v2 can't display map in play store

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

I am work with **Google Map Android API v2** in android application.

Work fine with in emulator with **Android Studio 1.0.2** .But when i am signed apk and upload into play store after i am donwload application from play store.

Just display white screen instead of map.and show me the google maps.

If anybody face this issue then please share with me.

I need help please..

thanks.

Comment: You need to sign it with you google maps key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Map API in the API console is associated with a signing key.

https://console.developers.google.com/project/

Look under credentials.

Your production application is probably signed with a different key than the one you are using for test.

You need to make sure the the key in you manifest for the API references the API key that
matches your signing key.

If the map key in the manifest is not created using the production signing key you will end up with a blank screen.

Comment: @Roger  keytool -list -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore C:\Users\myUser\.android\android.jks -storepass mystorepass -keypass mykeypass